# How do I create a sql sequence based on a specific column?

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I have to do something like the following example in SQL with a sequence for the VERSION column:

| ID | VERSION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 |

I mean, when a new record is entered with the same ID, the VERSION increases by 1, if it's a different ID it starts at 1 again for that ID, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `ROW_NUMBER()` Analytic Function such as

```
SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY 0) AS version
  FROM t
```

where `PARTITION BY` performs `GROUPING BY`, and `ORDER BY` stands only for being compulsory(*so, followed by an arbitrary constant*)